# Calculate average temperature (derived from other dataset) over start and end date in same row

Tags: r, time-series, average, mean

I am a beginner in R and I would like to calculate the average temperature over a certain time period. I have two datasets:

1. Dataset with the start date (date_fixed) and end date (date_broken)

   ```
   ds <- data.frame(  date_fixed= c("16-3-2015", "19-3-2015"), 
                      date_broken = c("18-3-2015", "22-3-2015"))

   ds$date_broken <- dmy(ds$date_broken)
   ds$date_fixed <- dmy(ds$date_fixed)
   ```
2. Dataset with temperature per day:

   ```
   weather <- data.frame(date = c("16-3-2015", "17-3-2015", "18-3-2015", 
    "19-3-2015", "20-3-2015", "21-3-2015"), temperature = c("10", 
    "11", "12", "11", "12", "11"))
   weather$date <- dmy(weather$date)
   ```

My desired output would look like this (I'm sorry, I can't figure out how to make it a nice table)

```
date_fixed date_broken average_temperature
2015-03-16     2015-03-18  11
2015-03-19    2015-03-22  11,3
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution using `lubridate` and `%within%`

```
library(lubridate)
ds$average_Temp <- sapply(interval(ds$date_fixed, ds$date_broken), function(i)
                               mean(weather$temperature[weather$date %within% i]))
ds
#  date_fixed date_broken average_Temp
#1 2015-03-16  2015-03-18     11.00000
#2 2015-03-19  2015-03-22     11.33333
```

Note: I converted temp to numeric as follows:

```
weather$temperature <- as.numeric(as.character(weather$temperature))
```

Comment: Thanks!
Now I also have other columns which I did not provide in the minimum working example above. Those columns have information about the locations in 'ds'  and 'weather'. I would like to calculate the avg_temp only if those locations are exactly the same, is it possible to add such a condition to your solution? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Nena. You will have to make an aggregation (group_by sort of thing). If you provide me with some data I will update my solution.

Comment: ds <- data.frame(  date_fixed= c("16-3-2015", "19-3-2015", "21-3-2015"), 
                   date_broken = c("18-3-2015", "22-3-2015", "24-3-2015"), location = c("A", "B", "B"),
                   position = c("1", "2", "2"))
-AND-
weather <- data.frame(date = c("16-3-2015", "17-3-2015", "18-3-2015", 
                               "19-3-2015", "20-3-2015", "21-3-2015", "22-3-2015", "23-3-2015", "24-3-2015"), 
                      temperature = c("10", "11", "12", "11", "12", "11", "13", "14", "12"), location = c("A", "B", "B"), position = c("1", "2", "2"))

Comment: So I would like to aggregate by 'location' and 'position'

Answer (score 3):

With the recently implemented `non-equi` joins feature in the [current development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table, v1.9.7`, this can be done as follows:

```
require(data.table) #v1.9.7
setDT(weather)[ds, mean(temperature), on=.(date>=date_fixed, date<=date_broken), by=.EACHI]
#          date       date       V1
# 1: 2015-03-16 2015-03-18 11.00000
# 2: 2015-03-19 2015-03-22 11.33333
```

This assumes `temperature` is numeric/integer type (as opposed to `factor` in your question).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `foverlaps` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'ds' and 'ds2' `data.frame` to `data.table` and set the key as 'date_fixed' and 'date_broken'.  Then apply `foverlaps` on the 'data.table's, get the `mean` of 'temperature', grouped by 'date_fixed' and 'date_broken'.

```
library(data.table)
ds2 <- data.frame(date_fixed=weather$date,
      date_broken = weather$date, temperature = weather$temperature)

setDT(ds2, key = c("date_fixed", "date_broken"))
setDT(ds, key = c("date_fixed", "date_broken") )

foverlaps(ds2, ds)[, .(avg_temp = mean(as.numeric(as.character(temperature)))) ,
            by = .(date_fixed, date_broken)]
#   date_fixed date_broken avg_temp
#1: 2015-03-16  2015-03-18 11.00000
#2: 2015-03-19  2015-03-22 11.33333
```

NOTE: The 'temperature' column was `factor`, so it needs to be converted to `numeric` for calculating the average.

---

Or using `base R`

```
ds$avg_temp <-  unlist(Map(function(x,y) with(weather, 
        mean(as.numeric(as.character(temperature[date >=x & date <= y])))) , 
        ds$date_fixed, ds$date_broken))
```

NOTE2 : Though, we can use `>` to do this, it is better to stick on with `foverlaps`

Answer (score 0):

I have used stringsAsFactors = FALSE in your weather data.frame definition

```
ds$average_temperature= apply(ds, 1, function(x)  mean(as.numeric(weather[weather$date >= x[1] & weather$date <= x[2],2])) )
```